# Flickity slider issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, flickity

Hi i'm using the flickity slider but there is a problem when i drag the items of the carousel: when i drag and move the slider and release it the cells are auto-aligned and the result, for me, is very bad. Now i don't want that this happen so do you know how to disable this feature?
This is the code use to create the swiper.

```
const swiper = new Flickity('.carousel', {
    prevNextButtons: false,
    contain: true,
    resize: true,
    pageDots: false,
    freeScroll: true  })
```

And this is the problem in a gif img: [Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ5QL.jpg)
Thanks.

Comment: Copying your options into one of their [codePen examples](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/yyvNaG) works, are you possibly overwriting the option somewhere else?

Comment: no man, i'm not overwriting nothing. IDK what to do